# Unity 3D 5.5.1 Как запустить анимацию через скрипт С#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал анимацию открытия верхней крышки сундука ChestOpen.anim. Надо чтобы при нажатии клавиши "E" запускалась анимация. Версия Unity 3D 5.5.1
Заранее спасибо за помощь!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animation anim; 

    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)){
          anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
          anim.Play("ChestOpen");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом.

Answer (score 3):

Короче после долгих мучений я нашел ответ! Анимация не запускалась из-за того что не стоит галочка Legacy
1 Выбираем нашу анимацию
2 Справа от надписи инспектор в выпадающем меню выбираем Debug
3 Ставим галочку напротив Legacy
4 Ставим обратно Normal вместо Debug
5 Готово! Наслаждаемся просмотром долгожданной анимации!

Answer (score 2):

Код будет работать, если ты ещё самому сундуку добавишь объект анимации.

Я сам добавлял ещё в скрипт

```
public AnimationClip a;
```

и помещал туда сам клип от объекта.
После этого вызываешь:

```
anim.Play(a.name);
```

Comment: Какой именно объект? Animation? Уже стоит. Все равно не работает

Comment: Сама анимация должна быть помещена в public AnimationClip ac1; А объект Animation anim - это анимация самого предмета, которая должна быть добавлена к нему в класс Animation

Comment: Все равно не работает. Заметил важный момент. Анимация которую я добавляю к anim убераеться при запуске игры. Пока игра запущена пытаюсь добавить ее но не получаеться. Я ее выбираю а она просто не добавлеться

Comment: все с этим разобрался теперь не изчезает но анимация все равно не проигровается

Comment: Скрипт ты на игрока вешаешь?
Справа от поля Animation скрипта нажимаешь точку для выбора и добавляешь Animation твоего объекта.
Потом справа от поля AnimationClip нажимаешь на точку и добавляешь саму анимацию, которую ты сделал

Comment: я канешно нуб но не настолько. я это сделал

Comment: Не работает. ХЕЛП

Comment: Ты в консоль смотрел? Есть ошибки?
Попробуй поискать с помощью консоли.

Comment: The AnimationClip 'ChestOpen' used by the Animation component 'SM_Chest_1_001' must be marked as Legacy.

Comment: The animation state ChestOpen could not be played because it couldn't be found!
Please attach an animation clip with the name 'ChestOpen' or call this function only for existing animations.
UnityEngine.Animation:Play(String)
Script:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/Script.cs:11)

Comment: Ты анимацию поместил и на сам сундук и в скрипт??
Он у тебя анимацию не может найти.

Comment: Тебе консоль даже говорит в каком месте ошибка. 
Ищи, смотри, исправляй.

Answer (score 0):

В окне Animator, где состояния объекта, нажмите на стрелку перехода от состояния покоя к нужному состоянию. В инспекторе найдите Settings, снимите все галочки и все значения установите на 0.